# object-fit solution for picture source srcset

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

I'm currently using picture srcset for responsive images and currently looking for a way to make it scale or cover the entire element or container, much like css `background-size: cover` or `object-fit`. I've read that object-fit only works on `img` tags is there an alternative for srcset. I'm using Drupal 8 responsive image module and it renders a `picture` element

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="/aim-beta/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/2017-08/admissions-banner-how-to-apply-alt.jpg?itok=O11apfmI 1x" media="all and (max-width: 480px)" type="image/jpeg">
    <source srcset="/aim-beta/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/2017-08/admissions-banner-how-to-apply-alt.jpg?itok=QrLnqmKd 1x" media="all and (max-width: 768px)" type="image/jpeg">
    <img srcset="/aim-beta/sites/default/files/2017-08/admissions-banner-how-to-apply-alt.jpg" alt="Admissions - How to Apply" typeof="foaf:Image">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

`object-fit` works on responsive images, because you style the `<img>`, not the `<picture>`.